# Excel Array formula with IF statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am not that great with array formulas in excel so I thought maybe someone in this community might be able help me.  I have data in two seperate worksheets and am trying to sum the information for given parameters.  The first worksheet looks like so

```
Start Date   End Date   Division and Group Total
10/1/2011   10/31/2011   [need sum here]
11/1/2011   11/30/2011   [need sum here]
    .            .
    .            .
    .            .
03/01/2015   03/31/2015  [need sum here]
```

The second worksheet contains the information which is as follows:

```
Year      Jan Feb Mar Apr  ...  Dec     Division   Group
2011       1   2   3   4   ...  21       Retail      A
2011       5   6   7   8   ...   2       MGMT        B
  .        .   .   .   .   ...   .        MW         C
  .        .   .   .   .   ...   .        BB         D
  .        .   .   .   .   ...   .        .          .
2015       5   5   5   5   ...   1       Retail      J
```

The group variable has 10 different distinct values while the division only has 4.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need more information on what exactly it is you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to sum information into worksheet 1 given information from worksheet 2.  For example: the row contains information from Retail and in group A sum the given information within October of 2011

Comment: Not exactly the way it would look, but have a look at making a pivot table of your data....

Comment: thanks for suggestion but in my experience referencing a pivot table in excel is rather cumbersome

Comment: Couple of questions. Is the time period for Start Date and End Date always going to be one month? Also, do you want to see ONE combined total for all divisions and groups by that one month OR one individual total for that month by Division and Group?

Comment: Can you provide an example of output for the given input above?  It is fairly difficult to see what you're going for.  Regarding Pivot Tables, referencing them is usually quite simple with `GETPIVOTDATA`, and I would also recommend them as a first step for doing aggregation type calculations like this.  A minute or two of Pivot configuration saves hours of formulas generation if they are appropriate.

Comment: Yes the time period will always be one month and yes, I would like to see ONE combined total for all divisions and groups by that one month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into SUMPRODUCT. You can use it to match multiple cells in a row and then sum them up. For example

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=2011)*(H1:H10="Retail")*(I1:I10="A")*F1:F10)
```

Just change the letters to what matches your sheet. Also the cell format type is important. For example you see that 2011 is unquoted because it is stored as a number. If it was stored as text then it would need to be "2011". The F corresponds to the column you want to total. In this case it is the October column. You can also add more criteria or subtract it.

You can also add the year dynamically off the start date with

```
YEAR(A1)
```

and make decisions based on more than one criteria per column with OR or AND

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=YEAR(Sheet1!A1))*(H1:H10="Retail")*OR((I1:I10="A"),(I1:I10="B"))*F1:F10)
```

Comment: Your Welcome. You can also get more in depth by using `` =INDIRECT(CHAR(64+MATCH(TEXT(A1,"mmm"),A1:K1,0))&"2"):INDIRECT(CHAR(64+MATCH(TEXT(A1,"mmm"),A1:K1,0))&"100") `` in place of `F1:F10` to dynamically assign the column based on the month in the start date. `A1` is the start date and change the 2 and 100 to be the rows that need to be checked. Please select this as an answer if you like it. Thanks

Comment: OR doesn't work as you might expect in array formulas because it returns just a **single** value (TRUE or FALSE) not an array. To get an `OR` effect you would need to use this syntax: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=YEAR(Sheet1!A1))*(H1:H10="Retail")*((I1:I10="A")+(I1:I10="B")),F1:F10)`

Comment: What I had did work for me but it may have been something to do with my small test data that I just made up. Thank you for that bit of information. I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and dont really know how to select answer, if you could please provide me the steps I would be happy to

Answer (score 0):

sheet2!$L$1:$W$1 are the month headers (ex Jan, Feb).

B2 is the End Date value.

sheet2!$K$2:$K$7 is the year column on sheet2 (Expand where necessary).

sheet2!$x$2:$x$7 is the group column on sheet2 (Expand where necessary).

c2 is the group value.

sheet2!$y$2:$y$7 is the division column on sheet 2 (Expand where necessary).

d2 is the division value.

sheet2!$L$2:$W$7 are all the values on sheet2 (Expand where necessary).

You will need to enter this formula by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

```
=SUM((Sheet2!$L$1:$W$1=TEXT(B2,"mmm"))*IF(Sheet2!$K$2:$K$7=YEAR(B2),IF(Sheet2!$X$2:$X$7=C2,IF(Sheet2!$Y$2:$Y$7=D2,Sheet2!$L$2:$W$7))))
```

Let me know if this is your desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot rwilson, I just tried the above formula and it works perfectly!  But I dont see how its subject to the division and group criteria for the given month.  I added these two parameters to your statement but returned a value of 0.

Comment: =SUM(('sheet2'!G2:R2=TEXT('sheet1'!B3,"mmm"))*IF('sheet2'!B3:B9142=YEAR('sheet1'!B3)&'sheet2'!S3:S9142='sheet1'!L3&'sheet2'!T3:T9142='sheet1'!L4,'sheet2'!G3:R9142))

where 

sheet2 G2:R2    = Month Headers
sheet1 B3       = end date
sheet2 B3:B9142 = Year
sheet1 B3       = end date year
sheet2 S3:S9142 = Divison in total data
sheet1 L3       = Division (retail, MGMT, MW,...,)
sheet2 T3:T9142 = Group in total data
sheet1 L4       = group (A,B,C,...,J)
sheet2 G3:R9142 = monthly data

Comment: The formula is now updated to include those two parameters.

Comment: I cant say it enough....this community is awesome!  Thanks everyone for the help, you've saved me a tremendous amount of time!